# Yii 1.15 CdbCriteria adds up own sorting - magic

Tags: php, yii, sql-order-by, yii-cactiverecord

It happens that Yii adds ordering by ID to criteria implicitly.

Pay attention to this line in code   **$criteria->order ='t.id ASC';**

My source code:

```html
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

            $criteria->select = 't.id, order_id, was_before, became, t.created_at';

            $criteria->addCondition('t.created_at >= \'' . $from . '\'');
            $criteria->addCondition('t.created_at <= \'' . $to . '\'');
            $criteria->alias ='t';


            $criteria->with = [
               'order' => [
                  'select' => 'm.id as b, m.status',
                  'condition' => 'm.status = ' . Order::STATUS_CANCELLED,
                  'alias' => 'm',
                  'with' => [
                     'packerRest' => [
                        
                        'select'=> 'g.id as n',
                        'alias' => 'g'
                     ]
                  ]
               ],
            ];
            
            $criteria->order ='t.id ASC';
```

Dump of Criteria:

[image]

Resulting error:

[image]

As you may see I didn't add sorting by ID. Yii does it somehow and breaks the whole query.

I'm already ready to rewrite it in pure MySQL.

Any ideas why it does so?

Comment: Maybe you have it in your relations to `order` or `packerRest` models?

Comment: yep, you are right, this is what I have in Order model :           'packerRest' => [self::HAS_MANY, 'PackerRest', 'order_id',
              'order' => 'id DESC'
           ],:  . if you rovide answer and I 'll accept it

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad I helped! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Yii` it's possible to define the ordering for related models in the model's `relations()` method via something like: `'packerRest' => [self::HAS_MANY, 'PackerRest', 'order_id', 'order' => 'id DESC' ]` which is what turned out to be in your `Order` model.

PS: We already figured out the issue in the comments of the question but I'm posting this answer so just we're in the SO format and to make it easier to find and read for others.